# Closing folders in list view

Tags: macos, finder, applescript

I'm looking for a way to close opened folders in the list view. I was thinking that applescript might have a way but I don't know what to look for.

[image]

Like here, I want to get the current selected folder and then go through each subfolder and close them. Is that possible or can anyone point me to the action that closes a folder?

Comment: You can option click on the disclosure triangle to open/close subfolders recursively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd> -Click the reveal arrow next to *foo*.

Alternatively,  <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>   <kbd>←</kbd>  will do the same thing.
 <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>   <kbd>→</kbd>  will re-open them all.

It appears Mojave closes them all by default now [though with no real consistency I can find], but previously opt/action was the way.

Comment: Oh thats brilliant! I didnt even know that was a thing. Thank you so much :)